# Panning image window programmatically openCV

Tags: python, opencv

im trying to **pan** my image (after zooming in) **using the RB event** instead of the LB event, but i can't find any information on how to do that.

i open an image using cv2.imshow(...) and zoom in on it. Now, holding and dragging the left mouse button i can pan across the image. I would like to enable this behavior when clicking the right mouse button instead.

**Catching/handling the RBDOWN event is not an issue,** but i don't know what to do afterwards. I would prefer not to use another library if possible (because of multi platform, maintenance and space)

possible solutions i can think of but am not sure how to implement:

- "reroute" RB click to LB click using a click event (this probably needs another library?)
- call the underlying panning function that triggers when LBDOWN+ drag happens (can't find anything on this?)

does anyone have ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I would dig in source code to see how it works. But source code can be in C/C++.

Comment: it seems C/C++ code uses `moveView()` in [mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* evnt)](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/1d2ef6b2a14fd5f80277d64b14e4a9a2faddc7d8/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp#L2792) to move image but it seems this function is not available in Python. Maybe ask author of cv2 for help